# Magento 1.7.02 Downloader Shows "Cannot Find command Sync" error after login

Tags: magento

I am trying to access the magento downloader, however, after logging in to the downloader with my admin credentials, I am shown a "Cannot find command sync" error instead of the screen that shows the list of installed modules.  Help?

I tried uninstalling modules via the system->configuration-->Advanced page in addition to setting true to false for newly installed modules in the app/etc folder.

Please help.

Comment: Are you using a VM? if so http://www.magentocommerce.com/boards/viewthread/262770/

Comment: I read that post.  Not sure what it means...

Comment: can you describe your development setup?

Answer (score 0):

I'm betting you probably have insufficient rights to the command `_Header.php` files on the directory `downloader/lib/Mage/Connect/Command`.

Snooping around at the file lib/Mage/Connect/Command.php yields the following function:

```
public static function registerCommands()
{
    $pathCommands = dirname(__FILE__).DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR.basename(__FILE__, ".php");
    $f = new DirectoryIterator($pathCommands);
    foreach($f as $file) {
        if (! $file->isFile()) {
            continue;
        }
        $pattern = preg_match("/(.*)_Header\.php/imsu", $file->getFilename(), $matches);
        if(! $pattern) {
            continue;
        }
        include($file->getPathname());
        if(! isset($commands)) {
            continue;
        }
        $class = __CLASS__."_".$matches[1];
        foreach ($commands as $k=>$v) {
            $commands[$k]['class'] = $class;
            self::$_commandsAll[$k] = $commands[$k];
        }
        self::$_commandsByClass[$class] = $commands;
    }
}
```

As a **stopgap**, you might want to try `chmod 777 /downloader` first and see what happens.

It would help if you could describe your development setup so we could shed more light on the issue. Is it Linux? Is it windows? Usually the above solution works on most linux setups.

**EDIT**

also, one more thing to check, if the above does not work:

run `php -i | grep -i pear` and see if you have pear in your include path.

Comment: Development setup is Linux.  Regarding those lines of code, what should i do with that.  I ran the command in linux, I think it shows I have pear, but not sure how I can tell

Comment: Did you `chmod 777` your `downloader/` folder? You might also want to pastebin the output of the `php -i` command